# Read python dict or yaml and call as python function with arguments and objects

Tags: python, object, dictionary, yaml

To read the below python dict or its equivalent yaml and generate equivalent python function call

```
mydict = {'RouteAdd': {'route_config': {'RouteConfig': {'table_name': 'my table', 'app_id': 'my app', 'nexthops': [{'NexthopInfo': {'nexthop_index': 2, 'nexthop_address': {'GatewayAddress': {'ethernet_mac': 'my mac', 'nexthop_ip': 'my ip'}}, 'if_name': 'my interface'}}]}}}}
```

Its yaml(for readability):

```
RouteAdd:
  route_config:
    RouteConfig:
      app_id: "my app"
      nexthops:
      - NexthopInfo:
          if_name: "my interface"
          nexthop_address:
            GatewayAddress:
              ethernet_mac: "my mac"
              nexthop_ip: "my ip"
          nexthop_index: 2
      table_name: "my table"
```

I would like to read the above kind of yaml or python dict and call as below:

```
RouteAdd(route_config=Routeconfig(app_id="my app",nexthops=[NexthopInfo(if_name="my interface",nexthop_address=GatewayAddress(ethernet_mac="my mac",nexthop_ip="my ip"),nexthop_index=2)],table_name="my table"))
```

Basically alternate hierarchy is an object. What I have pasted is a small clip. Looking for a recursive function that does this by reading either a yaml or python dict and convert it to above format so that I can call and execute the function. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def call_dict(d):
    k, v = list(d.items())[0]  # ('RouteAdd', {route_config: ...})
    kwargs = {}
    for k2, v2 in v.items():
        if isinstance(v2, dict):
            kwargs[k2] = call_dict(v2)
        elif isinstance(v2, list):
            kwargs[k2] = [(call_dict(v3) if isinstance(v3, dict) else v3) for v3 in v2]
        else:
            kwargs[k2] = v2
    return globals()[k](**kwargs)
```

Test:

```
def test1(t_arg=None, t_arg2=None):
    return t_arg + sum(t_arg2)

def test2(t_arg=None):
    return t_arg


res = test1(t_arg=1, t_arg2=[test2(t_arg=2), test2(t_arg=3)])
print(res)  # 6


test_dict = {
    'test1': {
        't_arg': 1,
        't_arg2': [
            {'test2': {'t_arg': 2}},
            {'test2': {'t_arg': 3}},
        ]
    }
}

res = call_dict(test_dict)
print(res)  # 6
```

**Upd:**

As string of code:

```
def str_of_code(d):
    k, v = list(d.items())[0]
    kwargs = {}
    for k2, v2 in v.items():
        if isinstance(v2, dict):
            kwargs[k2] = str_of_code(v2)
        elif isinstance(v2, list):
            kwargs[k2] = '[{}]'.format(', '.join(
                (str_of_code(v3) if isinstance(v3, dict) else repr(v3)) for v3 in v2)
            )
        else:
            kwargs[k2] = repr(v2)
    return '{}({})'.format(k, ', '.join('{}={}'.format(*i) for i in kwargs.items()))


test_dict = {
    'test1': {
        't_arg': 1,
        't_arg2': [
            {'test2': {'t_arg': 2}},
            {'test2': {'t_arg': 3}},
        ]
    }
}

res = str_of_code(test_dict)
print(res)  # test1(t_arg=1, t_arg2=[test2(t_arg=2), test2(t_arg=3)])
```

Comment: @germn Thanks for looking into. This works good but I would like to extract the output as a string to integrate this to my other part of work. So is it possible to extract the call format in string : "test1(t_arg=1, t_arg2=[test2(t_arg=2), test2(t_arg=3)])". Thanks again.

Comment: @germn , Its breaking for test_dict = {'test1':{'t_arg':1, 't_arg2':{'t_arg3':[{'a':1},{'b:2'}]}}}. Can you please help here?

Comment: @Suren what output do you expect for this?

Comment: @germn, If test_dict = {'func_name':{'input': {'AsList': {'a_list': [{'AEntry': {'entry':2, 'exit':3}}]}}}}, the expected output is func_name(input = AsList(a_list = [AEntry(entry=2, exit=3)]))

Comment: @Suren, and `str_of_code` works for this dict for me. (if you get error, with this dict, please, write error msg and line) But it wouldn't work for `{'some':[{'a':1},{'b:2'}]}` because it's unclear if `{'a':1}` part of `some`'s param or function `a` with wrong params.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107565/discussion-between-suren-and-gerasimov-mikhail).

Comment: @Germn, It works fine for integers but strips off the quotes for string values. Can you please take a look?If test_dict = {'func_name':{'input': {'AsList': {'a_list': [{'AEntry': {'entry':'hello', 'exit':'Thanks'}}]}}}} then the expected output is func_name(input = AsList(a_list = [AEntry(entry='hello', exit='Thanks')])). But it now returns => func_name(input = AsList(a_list = [AEntry(entry=hello, exit=Thanks)])) without single quote for the string value supplied. If the input contains quotes then it should be retained if not no need. Basically need to store input without modification.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the methods available suggested in the forum, but somehow none was working out for the solution that I was looking for. Hence, being a beginner, solved it by the below unorthodox way of finding and replacing. If someone have a better solution, please post it and I would like to use it.

```
api_map_complete = {api: {'config': {'AddressConfig': {'unit': 0, 'port_name': "my_name", 'address': "my address", 'family': 2}}}} 

def dict_to_obj(mystr,flag):
    global api_string
    if re.search(':\(',mystr):    
        if flag % 2 == 0:    
            api_string=mystr.replace(":(","(",1)
            flag=flag+1
        else:
            api_string=mystr.replace(":("," = (",1)
            flag=flag+1
        dict_to_obj(api_string,flag)
    else:    
        mystr=mystr.replace(":"," = ")
        mystr=mystr.replace(",",", ")
        api_string=mystr    

for combo in api_map_complete:    

    api_name=combo.keys()[0]
    for k,v in combo.iteritems():
        api_string=str(v)
        api_string=api_string.replace("{","(")
        api_string=api_string.replace("}",")")
        api_string=api_string.replace(" ","")
        api_string=api_string.replace(":'",":\"")
        api_string=api_string.replace("',","\",")
        api_string=api_string.replace("')","\")")
        api_string=api_string.replace("'","")
        dict_to_obj(api_string,1)
    #print api_string
    api_obj=api_name+api_string
    print api_obj
```

Comment: This cannot handle list of dicts