# How to split a python dictionary for its values on matching a key

Tags: python, dictionary

```
my_dict1 = {'a':1, 'chk':{'b':2, 'c':3}, 'e':{'chk':{'f':5, 'g':6}} }
```

I would like to loop through the dict recursively and if the key is 'chk', split it.
Expected output:

```
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'e':{'f':5}}
{'a':1, 'c':3, 'e':{'f':5}}
{'a':1, 'b':2, 'e':{'g':6}}
{'a':1, 'c':3, 'e':{'g':6}}
```

Not sure of how to achieve this. Please help.
What I have tried is below.

```
temp_list =[]
for k,v in my_dict1.iteritems():
    temp ={}
    if k is "chk":
        for key,val in v.iteritems():
            temp[key] = val
        my_dict1[k]={}
        for ky,vl in temp.iteritems():
            my_new_dict = copy.deepcopy(my_dict1)
            for k,v in my_new_dict.iteritems():
                if k is "chk":

                    my_new_dict[k] = {ky:vl}
            temp_list.append(my_new_dict)
print temp_list
```

output:

```
[{'a': 1, 'chk': ('c', 3), 'e': {'chk': {'f': 5, 'g': 6}}},
 {'a': 1, 'chk': ('b', 2), 'e': {'chk': {'f': 5, 'g': 6}}}]
```

How to make it recursive?

Comment: Have you tried coding this yet? can you show your code attempt and explain what parts of the implementation are giving you difficulty? And do you *have* to do this recursively?

Comment: `dict` cannot have duplicate keys. In your case, `my_dict` will be `{'a': 1, 'chk': {'f': 5, 'g': 6}, 'e': 4}`.

Comment: @yakym duplication will not be there in and hence the attempt.

Comment: @ldjaw , yes i just want to split but on recursively spliting, I am expecting the above output. For eg:{'a':1, 'b':2, 'e':4, 'chk':{'f':5, 'g':6}}, on spliting this again, we would get {'a':1, 'b':2, 'e':4, 'f':5}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'e':4, 'g':6}

Comment: @Suren have you any code to show for this?

Comment: @ldjaw, I tried poping the remaining keys and appending to a list to create list of dicts.it didnt work.

Comment: @Suren Show that code in your original question and provide some details on explaining the code you wrote.

Comment: @ldjaw , I have pasted the code i tried.

Comment: This is a follow-on question to [Split python dictionary to result in all combinations of values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36198540/4014959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import product


my_dict = {'a':1, 'chk':{'b':2, 'c':3}, 'e':{'chk':{'f':5, 'g':6}} }


def process(d):
    to_product = []  # [[('a', 1)], [('b', 2), ('c', 3)], ...]
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == 'chk':
            to_product.append([(k2, v2) 
                              for d2 in process(v) 
                              for k2, v2 in d2.items()])
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            to_product.append([(k, d2) for d2 in process(v)])
        else:
            to_product.append([(k, v)])
    lst = [dict(l) for l in product(*to_product)]
    unique = []
    [unique.append(item) for item in lst if item not in unique]
    return unique

for i in process(my_dict):
    print(i)

# {'e': {'f': 5}, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}
# {'e': {'g': 6}, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}
# {'e': {'f': 5}, 'a': 1, 'c': 3}
# {'e': {'g': 6}, 'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: @Germn , Thanks for responding :) I am getting syntax error for the line to_product.append([*d2.items()])

Comment: @Germn , This works great for me friend!! so just editing the line to have to_product.append(*[d2.items()])

Comment: @Suren, `[*d2.items()]` is correct and need for special nested cases like `{'chk':{'chk': 1}}`. May be it doesn't work because of older Python version. Try to change this to `[(k2, v2) for k2, v2 in d2.items()]` - it should work.

Comment: @Germn, got it. Thanks.

Comment: @Germn, Its breaking for this this my_dict = {'a':{'chk':{'ax':{'chk':{'b':2, 'c':3}}}}}. It returns only {'a': {'ax': {'c': 3}}} but not the other combination {'a': {'ax': {'b': 2}}}. Please suggest.

Comment: @Germn, Thanks, that works. I have edited to contain a couple of lines from your other solution to handle list of dicts here as well. Please validate if this is right. Eg: To handle->my_dict1 = {'a':[{'chk':{'ax':{'chk':{'b':2, 'c':3}}}}, {'chk':{'ax1':{'chk':{'b':2, 'c':3}}}}]}. Also need your suggestion on an other question as I feel you might have a better idea than the solution I arrived there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417729/read-python-dict-or-yaml-and-call-as-python-function-with-arguments-and-objects

Comment: @Suren, someone who will find this answer later might not understand part with lists handling. Let's leave answer as it is.

Comment: @Germn, Sure we can leave it as you said!. But the lists handling I have added here should work for me right? or did I miss something there?

Comment: @Suren it will work for some cases. It's hard to know about all without much testing.